# MYSQL TimeDiff do not subtract if it is 0 with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code on PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT
                    SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(HOURS.hour_enter, HOURS.hour_exit)))  AS hours,
                    SUM(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(HOURS.hour_enter, HOURS.hour_exit))) AS minutes
            FROM
                    HOURS
            WHERE
                    ........";
    $result = mysqli_query($connString, $sql) or die("Error");
    $reg = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $hoursWorked = $reg[0]+($reg[1]/60);
```

And my Table looks like:

```
+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|       id         |       hour_enter      |        hour_exit      |
+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|       1          | 2020-10-04 09:00:00   |   2020-10-04 12:00:00 |
|       2          | 2020-10-05 11:20:00   |   2020-10-04 17:00:00 |
|       3          | 2020-10-06 14:30:00   |   0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

But I get an incoherence with last line and the `hour_exit 0000-00-00 00:00:00`.The timediff prints for that line: 838hours and 59minutes, why?

Is any posibility to ignore if a `hour_exit` is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: if you add `WHERE hour_exit = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"` it will ignore those rows

Comment: I think @WOUNDEDStevenJones wants to say `!=` not equal to sign.

Comment: or you can consider `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as current_time `NOW()` in query, if that works for you

Comment: hehe, we do need that every now and then :)

Comment: How did you get `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the database? You need to find where in your application is a bug that lets you enter invalid date.